# How to set flash message in Yii2 after denied access to controller

Tags: php, redirect, yii2, flash-message

How to set flash message in Yii2 after denied access to controller?
Here is how deny access http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html :

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create', 'update'],
            'rules' => [
                // deny all POST requests
                [
                    'allow' => false,
                    'verbs' => ['POST']
                ],
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

after this it redirects to site/login. how can I make flash message there like "This section is only for registered users"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try adding a callback for denial? I hope this works:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create', 'update'],
            'rules' => [
                // deny all POST requests
                [
                    'allow' => false,
                    'verbs' => ['POST']
                ],
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied
            ],
            'denyCallback'  => function ($rule, $action) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'This section is only for registered users.');
                Yii::$app->user->loginRequired();
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add denyCallback to each rule:

```
    [
      'allow' => false,
      'roles' => ['@'],
      'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
         // callback logic
       }
    ]
```